# Сделать выделенную область кнопкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинка  на которой визуально есть несколько кнопок. Можно ли сделать эти кнопки кликабельными?

Comment: можно *(9 символов нужно...)*

Comment: посмотрите в сторону тега `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map